# Why does ($a = Foo) *>&1 write all streams to $a?

Tags: powershell

Suppose I have the following function:

```bsh
function Foo {
    Write-Information 'Info'
    Write-Warning 'Warning'
    Write-Verbose 'Verbose'
    Write-Error 'Error'
    return 'Return'
}
```

If I assign its output to a variable `$a`, all streams but the success stream get implicitly written to the terminal (assuming `$[Stream]Preference = 'Continue'`), while the success stream gets written to `$a`:

```bsh
PS1> $a = Foo
Info
WARNING: Warning
VERBOSE: Verbose
Foo : Error
At line:1 char:6
+ $a = Foo
+      ~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,Foo

PS1> $a
Return
```

Running `($a = Foo)` yields the same result, except that `Return` from the success stream also gets dumped to the terminal because of the expression evaluation caused by the parentheses. `$a` still gets the value `Return`.

If I redirect all streams to a file, `$a` still gets the value `Return` assigned and all streams are redirected as expected:

```bsh
PS1> ($a = Foo) *>output.txt

PS1> $a
Return

PS1> gc output.txt
Info
Warning
Verbose
Foo : Error
At line:1 char:7
+ ($a = Foo) *>output.txt
+       ~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,Foo

Return
```

But if I redirect all streams to the success stream instead, suddenly `$a` gets assigned the content of **all** streams:

```bsh
PS1> ($a = Foo) *>&1
Info
WARNING: Warning
VERBOSE: Verbose
Foo : Error
At line:1 char:7
+ ($a = Foo) *>&1
+       ~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,Foo
 
Return

PS1> # So far so good

PS1> $a
Info
WARNING: Warning
VERBOSE: Verbose
Foo : Error
At line:1 char:7
+ ($a = Foo) *>&1
+       ~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : NotSpecified: (:) [Write-Error], WriteErrorException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.WriteErrorException,Foo
 
Return

PS1> # ???
```

How can this behavior be explained? Especially the discrepancy between redirecting to file and redirecting to the success stream. I can understand that `$a = Foo *>&1` leads to `$a` containing everything, but would expect the parentheses to cause the expression to be evaluated *before* redirecting the streams. Or am I missing something here and the redirection applies before any evaluation? But then `$a` should be `$null` when redirecting to file, should it not?

Comment: Redirection operators affect the entire preceding statement block, and `()` is a _grouping construct_, not a statement boundary - try `$($a = Foo) *>&1` if you want to treat `$a = Foo` as a separate statement block (thus unaffected by redirection of the parent statement)

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen Thanks for the pointer. I'm however still unclear why redirection to file does work as I expected, even with just the grouping and not a statement boundary.  
If I understand you correctly `($a = Foo) *>output.txt` should yield `$a -eq $null`, but it doesn't.

Comment: No, it should not - grouping a single assignment makes powershell emit the right-hand side expression as evaluated - so what happens is 1) `Foo` is executed 2) since only _file redirection_, but no _stream merging_ is requested, only `stdout` is stored in  `$a`. 3) The grouping construct evaluates to `"return"` and this (along with the requested additional streams) is redirected to the file

Comment: Another way of thinking of it is that _stream merging_ (eg. `*>&1`) is handled by the command processor executing the affected statement (so it takes place _during execution_), whereas _file redirection_ (eg `*>somepath`) is only applied _after-the-fact_

Comment: @MathiasR.Jessen This difference between *file redirection* and *stream merging* is what I was missing, thanks! Along with your previous comments they make a great answer.